# WinForms - Programmatically adding lots of controls to a Panel at runtime

Tags: winforms

I need to be able to add several hundred instances of a custom control (UserControl) to a panel at once. When I do this using Controls.AddRange(), it hangs for a very long time. Is there something I need to do that will decrease the amount of time this takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding hundreds of instances of a control will be relatively slow no matter how you do it.

Are you currently calling myPanel.SuspendLayout() and myPanel.ResumeLayout()?  That will speed things up a bit.

If you describe your scenario in more detail, there may be a way to solve the issue without having hundreds of control instances active at the same time.

Comment: I've already tried using Suspend/Resume layout, so I'm guessing the answer is simply "I'm doing it wrong". I'll describe my situation in another question.

Comment: Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482353/winforms-custom-xml-editor